# UE4 bone sockets imported from blender have buggy local transform

Tags: unreal-4, blender, unreal

I'm exporting this armature with two sockets for left and right hands. As you can see on the Transforms location and rotation are all 0s.

[image]

Here's my export settings on blender:

[image]

Now I import it into UE4 and if I check the socket I get this:

[image]

The Y axis local transform has value -0.085241. And I cannot get rid of it for the life of me.

Comment: Does this produce a visibly different result in-game?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, it's visible. That's why I can't leave it be. The attached objects end up sticking out through hands and similar stuff.

Comment: That would be ideal to show in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I kind of found a workaround.

Firstly, I believe UE4 only allows to import sockets for static meshes and not for skeletal meshes. So what I was importing wasn't sockets, it was just adding them as bones to the rest of the skeletal tree.

Still doesn't explain the weird transform inconsistency. But it turns out having them imported as bones was even better. I simply added the socket within UE4 to the imported socket bone. Then I adjusted the sockets transform with the equivalent opposite value of the inconsistency and now the placement matches pixel perfect with what I see in blender.